# Is the URL generated by an AI search permanent and shareable?

Tags: support, search, overflow-ai

When I made an on-site [search via AI](https://stackoverflow.com/ai/search), it took me to a URL with a number in it.  e.g.:  https://stackoverflow.com/ai/search/14999.   Is this a permanent link?  Can other users see it?  Can this link be shared with others?  Will the content of my query and its AI-generated response appear at that link when others view it?

I notice that I need to be logged in to even see the content of that link correctly, so I'm not sure how it looks for other users.

Comment: Ryan, below, is correct. Links are not shareable. Out of curiosity, are you asking because you would like to share the link with someone, or is it more to ensure that your search can't be viewed by anyone else?

Comment: @EmmaBee I was surprised to see that each query had a unique URL so that inspired me to wonder if it was possible for me to make a search and then share the results with others.   I was also wondering if my searches and the generated responses were being stored permanently so that I can come back to them after some time to review them.  Incidentally, if the searches are permanent, I'm not sure how I would "search my searches" to find it again.  It seems it may be useful to respond to a question with a comment by providing an AI search prompt that adequately answers the question though.

Answer (score 7):

#### No

I clicked the link and got a 404 error, so it is at least not shareable.